# Rendering labels + icons for each arc element in doughnut chart (Vue-chartjs 4.0.2 + chartjs 3.7.1)

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

For my job I need to reproduce this doughnut Chart for our website that is using Vue Js:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTpsp.png)

I already succeeded in creating the doughnut chart using this library (vue-chartjs) but I’m really struggling with completing the arcs elements with icon + the labels of each arc elements.
I want to know if it is possible to add in each arc element an icon + the label attached to this arc element as in the image I uploaded.

I already tried to do it with a html / js project but I only succeeded in rendering images in arc elements but It’s quite difficult to have a good render with images with different sizes etc..

My environment is the following :

- Vue JS : 2.6.12
- Vue-chartjs : 4.0.2
- chart.js : 3.7.1

Any answer would be appreciated :D

Kind regards,

Calab.
[Here is the doughnut Chart I want to reproduce :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTpsp.png)

Comment: You can use the plugin api to draw anything you want on the canvas: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/developers/plugins.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.